# When I add a scroll with overflow:auto, my divs are no longer side by side

Tags: html, css

html code

```
 <section style= "
    height: 600px;
    width:800px;
    padding: 10px;">   <div id="vmap" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; width: 50%;
    height: 600px;
    width:800px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto; "></div><div style="margin-left: 50%;
    height: 600px;
    width: 800px;

overflow-y : scroll;"><table  style = "margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;">
  <tr>
    <th>Job Title</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Apply By: </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ><a href="https://jobs.undp.org/cj_apply.cfm?cur_job_id=70470" >Chargé (e) des Affaires Humanitaires Assistant ( 3 postes) </a></td>
    <td>Kinshasa, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td>Feb-10-17 </td>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "https://jobs.undp.org/cj_apply.cfm?cur_job_id=70417">Chauffeur </a></td>
    <td>Lubumbashi 1, Kalemie 2, Uvira 2, Bukavu 3, Goma 4, Beni 2, Bunia 2, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td>Feb-10-17 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "https://jobs.undp.org/cj_apply.cfm?cur_job_id=70495">Secrétaire Exécutif (ve)</a></td>
    <td>Goma, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td>Feb-10-17 </td>
 </tr>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "
https://jobs.undp.org/cj_apply.cfm?cur_job_id=70496">Assistant (e) à la gestion de l’information </a></td>
    <td>Kinshasa, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC 
</td>
    <td>Feb-10-17 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "https://jobs.undp.org/cj_apply.cfm?cur_job_id=70418">Assistant Administratif Common UN System </a></td>
    <td>Goma, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td>Feb-10-17 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><a href = "https://jobs.undp.org/cj_apply.cfm?cur_job_id=70420">Chargé de Finances et Voyages Assistant Common UN System  </a></td>
    <td>Kinshasa, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td>Feb-10-17</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "
https://jobs.undp.org/cj_apply.cfm?cur_job_id=70497">Assistant (e) Humanitaire de Terrain </a></td>
    <td>Kalemie ( 1 poste) & Uvira ( 1 poste), CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC </td>
    <td>Feb-10-17  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "https://jobs.undp.org/cj_apply.cfm?cur_job_id=70468">Chargé (e) des Affaires Humanitaires Assistant</a></td>
    <td>Bunia, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLI</td>
    <td>Feb-10-17  </td>
 </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href = "
https://jobs.undp.org/cj_view_job.cfm?cur_job_id=70469">Chargé (e) des Affaires Humanitaires/ rapportage Associé(e)</a></td>
    <td>Goma, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td>Feb-10-17</td>
 </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href = "
https://jobs.undp.org/cj_view_job.cfm?cur_job_id=70496">Assistant (e) à la gestion de l’information</a></td>
    <td>Kinshasa, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td>Feb-10-17</td>
 </tr>
     <td><a href = "



https://www.unicef.org/about/employ/?job=496654">Chief, Child Protection</a></td>
    <td>Kinshasa, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td> 12 Feb 2017 </td>
 </tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href = "https://www.unicef.org/about/employ/?job=501993" class="job-link" data-job-id="501993">REPUBLICATION Consultant international pour développer le positionnement stratégique d’UNICEF en milieu péri-urbain sur le secteur Eau, hygiène et assainissement (EHA)</a></td>
    <td>Democratic Republic of Congo</td>
    <td>11 Feb 2017 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "https://www.unicef.org/about/employ/?job=501991">REPUBLICATION Consultant international pour la CONCEPTION D’UN PROJET INTERSECTORIEL VISANT A REDUIRE LA MALNUTRITION CHRONIQUE DES ENFANTS</a></td>
    <td>Democratic Republic of Congo</td>
    <td>11 Feb 2017 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "https://careers.un.org/lbw/jobdetail.aspx?id=69804" class="job-link" data-job-id="501993">CHIEF OF STAFF [Temporary]</a></td>
    <td>Kinshasa, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td>15/02/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "
https://careers.un.org/lbw/jobdetail.aspx?id=69804">SUPPLY OFFICER</a></td>
    <td>Goma, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td>15/02/2017 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "https://careers.un.org/lbw/jobdetail.aspx?id=73331" class="job-link" data-job-id="501993">DIRECTOR, POLITICAL AFFAIRS [Temporary] </a></td>
    <td>Kinshasa, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td>14/02/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "
https://careers.un.org/lbw/jobdetail.aspx?id=73708">CONTINGENT OWNED EQUIPMENT ASSISTANT </a></td>
    <td>Beni, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC </td>
    <td>14/02/2017 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "
https://careers.un.org/lbw/jobdetail.aspx?id=73157" class="job-link" data-job-id="501993">ADMINISTRATIVE ASSISTANT  </a></td>
    <td>Kinshasa, CONGO, DEM. REPUBLIC</td>
    <td>14/02/2017</td>
  </tr>
</table></div></section>
```

The code above is to add two divs side by side.  One dive, the one on the right, hold a JQVMap and the one on the left holds a table.  When I don't add overflow:auto they are next to each other but when i add overflow:auto the right div(with the table) goes below the other one.  I need a scoll bar and both divs beside each other.

Comment: they are bigger than the width. You must take in consideration the width of the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

You could either have to set the `<section>`'s style to `white-space: nowrap`, with the `<div>`'s style set to `display: inline-block` or you could use `overflow-x: auto` to force the container to have only horizontal scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <section style= "
    height: 600px;
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px;">   <div id="vmap" style="width: 800; height: 600; width: 50%;float:left;
    height: 600px;
    width:60%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;"></div><div style="margin-left: 50%;
    height: 600px;
    width: 40%;
    overflow:scroll;">
```

This helped